# Allowing a user to run Google App Script without having permissions to specific sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-permissions

I am trying to allow employees with in my organization run a App Script, without giving them access to some of the companies secured sheets. I have tried using .addEditor(emailAddress) and then remove those permissions at the end, but in order to do that, the user needs to have permission [CLICK HERE to see script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKEcq.png) to said page.

Comment: Please add the scripts to the question.  Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: Try installable triggers

Comment: The script is in the enter image description

Comment: As @TheMaster has said maybe you could try to make it work with triggers, or other resource without needing to actually change sheets permission. When is exactly that you need to execute Apps Script?